# Possible to create sockets with Node.js in Vagrant synced folder?

Tags: linux, node.js, sockets, vagrant

I've created a Vagrantfile config for my box that includes this line, setting permissions on my synced folder to 777 just to make sure its completely writeable:

```
dev.vm.synced_folder "apps/", "/httpd", :owner=> 'stella', :group=>'stella', :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
```

After I boot up the CentOS 6.4 vagrant box and ssh in I can confirm:

```
$ ls -la /httpd
drwxrwxrwx.  1 stella stella  442 Nov 11 09:33 june
```

And I can throw this into the top of my index.js file:

```
fs.writeFile("/httpd/june/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

And when I run `node index.js` node runs my script and successfully creates a file.  This is all to confirm that node can successfully write new files in my project's root path.  I've also moved my program outside of the synced folder and it runs flawlessly.

The issue I'm having is with creating sockets.  I have a couple high-profile node modules that are expected to create sockets in my project's root path, however I get a `Error: Operation not permitted` error whenever node.js attempts to create a socket and my program exits.

The sockets I'm attempting to create are:
- 127.0.0.1:3005
- 127.0.0.1:3006

I have been able to find almost nothing about this issue online other than [this blog post](http://samplacette.com/node-js-net-module-server-listen-socket-eperm-error/) that says it is impossible for Node.js to create sockets on a shared/synced folder.

The node modules I'm using are cluster-master and zmq.  cluster-master shuts down once it reaches this line: https://github.com/isaacs/cluster-master/blob/master/cluster-master.js#L119.

node-zmq shuts down when I try to bind my server to a port (apparently I can't post more than two links, so much for providing as much info as I can!): If you can find Justin Tulloss's zmq via google my server is forced to shut down once it reaches line 218 of lib/index.js, the Socket.prototype.bind function.

The reason why I thought it was a permissions problem is that both of these modules will write files to my project's root when successfully started: ZMQ for the sockets and Cluster-Master for the REPL, and if I move my project to, say, /var/www/june I have no problems whatsoever.  My program starts, cluster-master and zmq write their files, and I can communicate over the ports no problem.

My issue only lies with the Vagrant synced folder.

I guess I'm asking if it is indeed impossible to create sockets in a shared folder this way.  If so, is there anything I can do as a work-around?

Keeping my apps in a shared folder is desirable because my team and I can work on the files with or without the vm running, I can use the IDE environment on my host machine, etc.

**update:**
In cluster-master, if I change the line in the source:

```
var socket = path.resolve('cluster-master-socket')
```

to:

```
var socket = path.resolve('/tmp/cluster-master-socket')
```

cluster-master no longer causes my server to exit.  I don't see any easy fix like that for ZMQ, however.  This actually confuses me as to what exactly is causing the error, writing a file or opening a socket?

Comment: First guess: you are trying to bind ports < 1024 and your process is running as a non-root user. Try using ports >= 1024.

Comment: That's a great guess and I should have included the port numbers in my question but the ports I'm attempting to bind to are all above 3000.  I can also run node as root and I receive the same `Error: Operation not permitted`

Comment: "expected to create sockets in my project's root path". Do you mean TCP sockets or unix domain sockets? Because TCP sockets have nothing to do with the filesystem or paths at all. Unix domain sockets are subject to filesystem permissions, though.

Comment: I added some more information with what lines exactly are causing the errors.

Comment: I didn't actually answer your question, I'm using TCP sockets for ZMQ and it looks like cluster-master creates a TCP socket as well.

Comment: Third guess: SELinux?

Comment: That's also a really good guess and I wish I had thought of it before.  I really wanted that to be it but I've disabled SELinux, rebooted and the problem persists.